# Changing size of spinners in my MainActivity code

Tags: android

I know how to change size of elements in the xml code, but is it possible to do so in the Main activity (java) code? I've programmed my code to duplicated spinners in my code to appear on the screenbut I want them to be of a smaller width (currently they span the width of the screen). Below is my create.java code.

Thank you!

**create.java**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button buttontest;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

        //mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner

        Button duplicateSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bt_duplicate);
        duplicateSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {




            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);
                // Add another spinner



            }
        });

       // Button getSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bt_getSpinner); //code for getspinner
        //getSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          //  @Override
           // public void onClick(View view) {

           //     for (int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {      // Read all spinners
           //         Spinner spinner = mSpinners.get(i);
           //         Log.i("TAG", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
          //      }
         //   }
      //  });
    }


    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }


    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code. what you tried yet ?

Comment: Code has been edited in. I haven't tried anything yet because I don't even know if it is possible to do what I intend; is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)layout.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = 250;//pixels
    layoutParams.width = 250;//pixels
    spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

for convert `dp` to `Px`

```
public static int convDpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I put that into my code, but at the layout.getLayoutParams it says 'layout' -  qualifier must be an expression. What does that mean?

Comment: you can use `spinner` you spinner object name instead of `layout`

Comment: thanks. is it possible to set the position for where my first spinner will be placed?

Comment: u can like this `layoutParams.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);`

Comment: is this the right way to use it                 layoutParams.setMargins(int 20, int 20, int 20, int 20)

Comment: this is right way `layoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)`

Comment: Thank you! Last question (sorry). The spinners that im creating have a triangle in the bottom left corner of the spinner, but most spinners have the triangle just on the left side . why is mine not like that